# Null Conditional Operator in C# 5

Tags: c#

In c# 6, there is the new Null Conditional Operator, like so:

```
var name = p?.FirstName;
```

What can we use in c# 5 so that we don't have to resort to:

```
var name = null;
if(p != null)
    name = p.FirstName;
```

Comment: `var name = p!=null?p.FirstName:null;` ?

Comment: An extension method, but that won't save you much typing.

Comment: The reason the operator was added to C# 6 was because there was no easy syntax in C# 5.  If there had been then the feature would not have needed to be added.

Comment: `null` conditional operator is C#6 feature, what you do in `C#5` is already correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lashane has the same idea I did. Using a conditional operator can save you some time

the basic idea is that you evaluate if something is true or false, and give the values you want to put in for either.

```
var name = p != null ? p.FirstName : null;
```

The above is saying: "If p != null, conditional (?) set to p.FirstName when true, null when false"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zakwfxx4(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: FYI, that's called the conditional operator.  Ternary is a more board name that would apply to any operator that takes 3 operands, it just turns out this is the only one like that in C#.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my post and added a link to the microsoft site for this

Comment: It's worth noting that `?.` is an atomic operation while the conditional operator is not.

Answer (score -1):

I has a same idea.
And this is what I did:

```
public static T IsNull<T>(this T value) where T : new()
{
    if (value != null)
        return value;
    else
        return new T();
}
```